# Python, check element X from substrings

Tags: python, find, substring

I am trying to check if the element from position X in each sublist is same. like:

we have List of lists:

```
s= [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
```

And i want to check that the 3rd element is same in all sublists. Like in this example should go true only for second and third sublists

```
for x in s:
    if x[2] == 1:
        print "T"
```

Tried to print them but this just prints them every single time when it goes in for. i want just to check if third element from list is same in subslist

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'substrings'. Do you mean sub lists?

Comment: You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to collect all elements at a position, e.g. `list(zip(*s))[2]`

Comment: yes, i mean sublists, my bad...

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the value you're checking against, get the corresponding value from the first entry. Alternatively, get the 3rd value from all entries (using map or a list comprehension) then use something like `reduce` to check that they're all equal. Or a set: if you feed a sequence to a set and end up with a single element, all items were equal, so `len({entry[2] for entry in s}) == 1`.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all`.

```
s= [[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
if all(map(lambda x:x[-1],s)):
    print('T')
else:
    print('N')
```

Or you can `zip`.

```
x= zip(*s) 

if len(set(x[-1]))==1:
    print('T') 
else:
    print ('N')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
decision = 'T'
s= [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]

for x in s:
    if x[2] != 1:
        decision = "F"
        break
print(decision)
```

Output:

```
F
```

Alternatively:

```
if all(x[2] == 1 for x in s):
    print('T')
else:
    print('F')
```

If you don't know the `3rd` element in advance:

```
if len({x[2] for x in s}) == 1:
    print('T')
else:
    print('F')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of approach is wrong,
As for my understanding of the question, you need to check if the 3rd element in the list is same for all the elements in the list, use a function like this which return True is same element else False.

```
def is_same(s) :
    temp = s[0][2]  # temporarily save the 3rd element in a variable
    for x in s :    # loop through all the elements
        if x[2] != temp :  # check for the miss match
            return False
    return True

s = [[0,0,1], [0, 1, 1], [0,1,1]]

print(is_same(s))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s= [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]]
pos=2
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if i<j:
            if s[i][2]==s[j][2]:
                print (s[i],s[j])
```

in this code compare all of subletting and if the number in last pos is the same, print 2 list.

output:

> `[0, 0, 1] [0, 1, 1]`

Comment: The question is about checking if all third items are the same, not about printing them.